# how can one go about retrieving the latest occurrence of that specific record When the identifying fields are in two separate columns?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

[Example Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHx60.png)

As you can see i have two rows in a data table i need to get the latest occurrence of a document. A document is identified by a GUID if a request is sent out, and all other amendments/cancellations to this document are created as a new record in my data table but instead of carrying a GUID they are identified using an original Request Identifier (Original GUID of the first request) i only want to return the latest occurrence so if no amendments/cancellations exist then i only want to return the original request  else if there is an amendment or a cancellation then i need to return that record in my Data table. At this point i have attempted an inner join but received too many results to make sense of where i went wrong i have thought about using some sort of merge between two temp tables but at this point i am out of ideas. In a short summary i need to get the latest record potentially by using processing date on a unique Dataset once i have combined my GUID and Original Request Identifier Columns Any Suggestions?

[SQL Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7IMk.png)

Comment: Please show us the code, the expected, the actual result and the difference between the two. Also, it wouldn't hurt to break up your problem description into separate paragraphs.

Comment: It sounds like your Database design is fundamentally flawed and needs revision. If a table has to reference itself, it sounds like *something* should have been moved out into a seperate table a while ago. Right now you have `GUID` or `OriginalGUID` as primary key, wich is just utterly wrong. I heard of compound priamry keys, but never of a alternating primary key.

Comment: @Christopher This is the data table that has been returned by a web service the actual DB has an ID field as the primary key. the GUID and OrginalGUID are just normal User fields in the database which i am now trying to further query

Comment: @LajosArpad At this point i dont have any code as i have been trying to work it out in SQL before i do the same in code. My expected result is if i have only a request which is known as only a request has a GUID populated and each process must begin with a request then i should return the request. If an amendment or a cancellation to the document has been made then i must rather return the latest amendment/cancellation to the request. The two match based on GUID and Original Request Identifier as an original Request Identifier will always have the GUID of the Original Request.

Comment: Your SQL code is interesting then. That's code as well. I cannot improve a code I do not see written for a schema I do not know. You need to provide more information so we can help you.

Comment: Advice for writing a good question: 1. Learn how to use punctuation and paragraphing when asking questions.  2. Provide SQL information (table definitions, sample data, and desired output) as text, not images. 3. If you must use images, embed them in the post, do not use links.   .... If you ignore this sort of advice, your question will get little attention.

Comment: You say you're trying to figure this out in SQL first. Can you at least supply the SQL code you're trying to get to work?

Comment: @LajosArpad I have added the SQL Example, As you can see i am returning both the amendment and the cancellation records using my inner Join on the two user fields. my expectation is to return only the cancellation record as it is the last update to the document. And if no Amendment or cancellation exists it will return nothing.

Comment: Thank you. I still need some information though. You are using some terms here, like 'amendment' and 'cancellation'. Does 'amentment' mean that UserField15 has a value, but not UserField14?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be overthinking it to me: you want to group the rows with the same `GUID` or `Original Request Identifier` together, than take the row with the latest `Processing Date`. You can do this almost directly:

```
var ans = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("GUID")) ? r.Field<string>("Original Request Identifier") : r.Field<string>("GUID"))
            .Select(rg => rg.OrderBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Processing Date")).Last())
            .CopyToDataTable();
```

Since you didn't specify, I used `string` for the GUID row type and assumed the original table was named `dt`.

I like using an extension method analogous to `??` for `null` or empty strings:

```
public static string NotEmptyOr(this string src, string other) => String.IsNullOrEmpty(src) ? other : src;
```

Then you don't have to repeat the `GUID` field reference:

```
var ans = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("GUID").NotEmptyOr(r.Field<string>("Original Request Identifier")))
            .Select(rg => rg.OrderBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Processing Date")).Last())
            .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following Join :

```
            var query = (from dr1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                         join dr2 in dt.AsEnumerable() on dr1.Field<string>("GUID") equals dr2.Field<string>("Origina Request Identifer")
                         select new { dr1 = dr1, dr2 = dr2 }
                         )
                         .Select(x => (x.dr1.Field<DateTime>("Processing Date") > x.dr1.Field<DateTime>("Processing Date")) ? x.dr1 : x.dr2)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: It didnt work it failed for specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Then the type in the angle brackets need to be changed to match the type in the table.

Comment: var query = (from dr1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     join dr2 in dt.AsEnumerable() on dr1.Field<string>(MandateRequestFile.GUID) equals dr2.Field<string>(MandateAmendmentFile.OriginalRequestIdentifier)
                     select new { dr1 = dr1, dr2 = dr2 }
                          )
                          .Select(x => (DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(x.dr1.Field<string>(TableDefinitionDescriptions.ProcessingDate)),Convert.ToDateTime(x.dr1.Field<string>(TableDefinitionDescriptions.ProcessingDate))) > 1 ? x.dr1 : x.dr2))
                          .CopyToDataTable();

Comment: Did this which nearly worked except as i mentioned it only returned the requests which had amendments/cancellations but didn't return just the requests as well i.e records with just a GUID and no corresponding amendment/cancellation record

Comment: You can return whatever you want instead of : ? x.dr1 : x.dr2  You can use ? new { n = x.dr1, o = x.dr2 } : new { n = x.dr2, o = x.dr1}

Comment: Uses Left Outer Join : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause